# Apk working well on Lollipop, but not on Jelly Bean and Marshmallow

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-4.1-jelly-bean

When I am using my phone with android Lollipop all of my functions works good, but, when I am using Android Marshmallow or Jelly Bean app crashes.

Following is the build gradle file for app module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.k.sms"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

And this is my logcat when I testing my app in emulator with android Marshmallow

```
12-26 19:10:41.860 18000-18000/com.example.k.sms D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
   12-26 19:10:41.860 18000-18000/com.example.k.sms E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.example.k.sms, PID: 18000
                                                               java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: uid 10057 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.
                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendTextForSubscriber(ISms.java:768)
                                                                   at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessageInternal(SmsManager.java:310)
                                                                   at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:293)
                                                                   at com.example.k.sms.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:149)
                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: What the stacktrace say?

Comment: Everything seems fine here. May be problem with other things.

Comment: "is crashed"  -- use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: My app using android.permission.SEND_SMS. , can marshmallow considers it dangerous?

Comment: java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: uid 10057 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS. from your logcat, it is a dangerous permission you should figure out how to handle it: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html check that out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> targetSdkVersion 23

and

> java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: uid 10057 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.

It seems you just bumped `targetSdk` being unaware of consequences. Marshmallow introduces runtime permissions model that kicks off when you target API23 or higher and your app simply must support new runtime permission model as manifest declared permissions are no longer sufficient in such case.

Quick solution is to set `targetSdk` to `22` (or lower) as only then runtime permissions won't kick off. Quoting [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html):

> On all versions of Android, your app needs to declare both the normal
>   and the dangerous permissions it needs in its app manifest, as
>   described in Declaring Permissions. However, the effect of that
>   declaration is different depending on the system version and your
>   app's target SDK level:
>
> - If the device is running Android 5.1 or lower, or your app's target
>     SDK is 22 or lower: If you list a dangerous permission in your
>     manifest, the user has to grant the permission when they install the
>     app; if they do not grant the permission, the system does not install
>     the app at all.
> - **If the device is running Android 6.0 or higher, and
>     your app's target SDK is 23 or higher**: The app has to list the
>     permissions in the manifest, and it must request each dangerous
>     permission it needs while the app is running. The user can grant or
>     deny each permission, and the app can continue to run with limited
>     capabilities even if the user denies a permission request.

If you require anything not available in older APIs and must keep `targetSdk` 23 or higher, then you must have runtime permission supported though (there are some external libs helping with this).

Answer (score 0):

provide sms permission in manifest for lollipop and other lower versions  and add Marshmallow permission checks for higher than lollipop as explained in Runtime permissions in android